# Can I always expect assemblies that are part of the .NET Framework itself reside in the GAC?

Tags: .net, gac

I'm mostly just curious about this. Do assemblies that would be considered "part" of the .NET Framework itself **always** exist in the GAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - .NET framework assemblies are installed to the GAC when the .NET framework is installed